# How is the permutation done in this example?

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

I have confusion in understanding how the permutation is done in this example.[image: Example Graph Isomorphism]

Comment: Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.

Comment: Re previous comment, notice that I edited your posting to embed the image directly into your posting.  For help managing images on this forum, see the **Edit-Images** section of the protocol article that I linked to in the previous comment.

Comment: They are giving $\phi$ in [cycle notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Cycle_notation). The notation means that each entry in the tuple is mapped to the next entry, and the last entry to the first. Namely $\phi(1)=2,\phi(2)=4,\phi(4)=3,\phi(3)=1$, and $\phi(5)=5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permutation $\phi$ is being written in cyclic notation, so you interpret $\phi = (1, 2, 4, 3)$ as meaning $\phi(1) = 2, \phi(2) = 4, \phi(4) = 3, \phi(3) = 1, \phi(5) = 5$ - within the cycle, each element is mapped to the next one in the list (wrapping around when you get to the end), and anything not listed in the cycle stays unchanged.

If we just relabel the nodes in the graph without changing their position, the diagram looks like this:

[image: A diagram showing how the given permutation relabels the nodes in the graph without rearranging them.]

Then to get from the right-hand side of this image to the one you've posted, you just have to move the nodes back to their original position.